# How to set zoom level to user location in MapView

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview

Im using MKMapView to get the users location and when the view loads it shows the whole world view. Is there anyway that I can set a zoom level so that the users don't have to keep zooming in always to get the city view or street view...It would be a great help. I've posted my code below for reference...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ self.mapView.delegate self];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

---

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 500, 500);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


    }
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [_mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted should work for the most part *except* for this critical line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[ self.mapView.delegate self];
```

**Essentially, this line does nothing.

It is *not* setting the map view's `delegate` property (which is what I assume it is supposed to do).**

What it is actually doing is *calling* `self` on the `delegate` property.

The map view's `delegate` is not getting set (it stays `nil`) and so the `didUpdateUserLocation`  delegate method never gets called and so the map is not zooming to the user's location.

The line should be this:

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

or even simpler:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

Note that in iOS 5 or later, you can just set [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW61) and the map view will automatically zoom to and follow the user's location so you don't have to do it manually.

Also note that since iOS 6, `viewDidUnload` is deprecated and is not even called by the OS.  You probably want to move the disabling of `showsUserLocation` to `viewWillDisappear` (and move the enabling to `viewWillAppear`).

Comment: I have another doubt if you don't mind. I would like to add a button to the mapView so that when the user taps it would bring the mapView back to his current location if he has navigated through it....

Comment: If you keep the code as-is (updating setRegion in didUpdateUserLocation), map will already keep going back to user location whenever the device moves even if user scrolls/pans the map.  If you're not doing that anymore, then in the button action method, you call setRegion the same way except instead of `userLocation coordinate` use `mapView.userLocation.location coordinate`.

Comment: what value should I place in the coordinate

Comment: See previous comment: Instead of `[userLocation coordinate]` use `[mapView.userLocation.location coordinate]`.  If you still have trouble, please post another question with the code you tried.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur patience in helping me out..using setRegion showed some error, but I used `[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];`it worked just fine..;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this May be Help full for you

```
MKCoordinateRegion startupRegion;
        startupRegion.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.0000, 75.00);
        startupRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.597129);
        [mapViewObj setRegion:startupRegion animated:YES];
```

here 26.0000 and 75.00 is user location and MKCoordinateSpanMake is zoom level. It's increasing your zoom as you wish.

Comment: I tried the above code it throws an exception on running it...:( Thanks for the quick response anyways...

Comment: this code i'm using in my app. It's working fine. What's error you getting now...

Comment: it doesn't show any error but throws an exception on running the app. It happens only when I load the MapView ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In ViewDidLoad

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516; // your latitude value
zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806; // your longitude value
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.18; // change as per your zoom level
span.longitudeDelta=0.18;    
region.span=span;
region.center= zoomLocation;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Comment: I tried your above code but i want to zoom into users current location how can i obtain the users current latitude and longitude points..?

Comment: instead of that static value, you use mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.lattitude
mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude

Comment: @NotaGeek to get current location

Answer (score 0):

set MKCoordinateRegion and change region span according to your requirement

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
        CLLocation* currentLocation = (CLLocation*)from ; // current location
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
            maxLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < minLat)
            minLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
            maxLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < minLon)
            minLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
        region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
        region.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.4; // change as per required zoom level
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.4; // change as per required zoom level
```

// input that region and set map area as below 30000

```
   _mapView.region =MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation.coordinate,30000, 30000);
[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [_mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [_mapView reloadInputViews];
```

// center your map at Current location

```
    _mapView.centerCoordinate = _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
```

// To get current location use CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
    @interface GetCurrentLocation : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
    @property(nonatomic,strong)CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
    -(void)getLocation;
    @end

-(void)getLocation{

       _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
       [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
       _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
       [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

      }

       - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation// you can get current location here 
      {
       CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

       coord.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
       coord.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

      }
      - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
      {
           // NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.3;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.3;
    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When showing code in an answer, it is often helpful to add a little explanation how the code solves the OP's problem. You could [edit] this into your post. Kind regards!